# how to use abode flex application components in angular application

Tags: angular, apache-flex, migration

I am migrating the flex application into angular. Currently we have very heavy flex components, which takes much time to develop/ convert into angular. So we would like to use flex components in angular.  I have following questions.

1. Can we use / Is there any way to support the flex components in the angular2 application?
2. I am using spring security. How can I manage the session between flex component 
   and server in angular app.

Comment: If you have two questions, then you should ask two questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can open your angular application into flex and communicate angular to flex and vice versa with the help of Iframe.

Use : IFrame 
calling Flex code from Angular code use.
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFlexLoadDealDeatails", "yourfunction");
Calling Angular from Flex:
iframe.callIFrameFunction("angular function",["parameter if required"]);